# Mahout single-machine performance

Tags: java, mahout

I am developing a Java based application and I decided to use machine learning algorithms implemented in Mahout library. My application will run on single machine, without Hadoop.

I would like to ask, if single node Mahout has also overhead, like distributed one? I read in a book Mahout in action, than multiple cluster Mahout has some overhead (initializing, transfering data, etc.). But if we use Mahout algorithms without MapReduce paradigm, there should be no overhead, right?

Comment: Some of the algorithms have non-distributed versions (meaning no hadoop). You should use those if available for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make a difference whether you run it in a single machine or a 1000-node cluster. Hadoop  serializes all the intermediate data (MAP's key-value output), and persist it on the disk. In the reduce phase, it loads the key-value pairs back into the memory. Therefore, it has huge processing and disk-access overheads.

Basically, if you have few machines (e.g. <7 machines), hadoop is possibly not a good choice, specially for speedup analysis. In this case, you may just use the small cluster to check your code's logic before deploying it on a larger environment.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because Im asking about algorithms which don't use hadoop. These group of algorithms is appropriate for middle size data (and I think that MapReduce is not used, but Im not sure). Do they also use serialization?

Comment: @HIP_HOP Well, Mahout is created to be run on top of Hadoop, using map-reduce paradigm. I don't think they have implemented a serial version without map-reduce.

Comment: However, if you want to use scalable machine learning tools for single machine or limited number of machines (not fully scalable versions), you may try graphlab or [spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/)